# Tarkkonen's rho - Reliability or Validity

Tags: anova, spearman-rho

Kindly advise what the value we obtain for Tarkkonen's rho tells us about - reliability or validity of the data being measured.
Thank you

Comment: Dear user39531, you asked 21 questions on this site and got for 16 at least one answer. But your vote count shows only ONE up vote and nothing else. Moreover, no answer has ever been accepted by you. Accepted answers and up votes are, however, sort of the daily meal for people offering their time in order to help people which only contribute by questions - people like you. Please appreciate answers with votes, accept them and make us smile.

Answer (score 1):

Tarkkonen's $\rho_{uu}$ is a measure of reliability, but $\rho_{uy}$ is defined as a predictive validity parameter in the original article <sup><sub>([Tarkkonen & Vehkalahti, 2005](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X04001800))</sub></sup>. This article discusses both reliability and validity within Tarkkonen's proposed framework based on a measurement model. It appears to be applicable to structural validity as well. I'm not sure it belongs wholly to either class. Nonetheless, [Vehkalahti, Puntanen, and Tarkkonen <sup><sub>(2007</sub></sup>](https://wiki.helsinki.fi/download/attachments/33885362/Preprint439.pdf)<sup><sub>; see also [2006](https://wiki.helsinki.fi/download/attachments/33885362/Preprint430.pdf))</sub></sup> refer to *Tarkkonen's rho* as a "general estimator of reliability", so maybe that would be the safest bet if one had to choose.

---

<sup>**References**

**·** Tarkkonen, L., & Vehkalahti, K. (2005). Measurement errors in multivariate measurement scales. *Journal of Multivariate Analysis, 96*(1), 172–189. Retrieved from http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X04001800.

**·** Vehkalahti, K., Puntanen, S., & Tarkkonen, L. (2006). Estimation of reliability: A better alternative for Cronbach's alpha. *Reports on Mathematics, 430*, Department of Mathematics and Statistics, University of Helsinki, Finland. Retrieved from https://wiki.helsinki.fi/download/attachments/33885362/Preprint430.pdf.

**·** Vehkalahti, K., Puntanen, S., & Tarkkonen, L. (2007). Effects of measurement errors in predictor selection of linear regression model. *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis, 52*(2), 1183–1195. Retrieved from https://wiki.helsinki.fi/download/attachments/33885362/Preprint439.pdf.

**·** Vehkalahti, K., Puntanen, S., & Tarkkonen, L. (2009). Implications of dimensionality on measurement reliability. In B. Schipp & W. Kräer (Eds.), *Statistical inference, econometric analysis and matrix algebra* (pp. 143–160). Heidelberg: Physica Verlag.</sup>